# Can't read the value that comes with the GATT Service characteristic; Not sure if I setup the GATT server correctly

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, android-ble, bluetooth-gatt

The BLE is advertising just fine. I can establish a connection with it but I can't read the characteristic value I set here on the initialization of GATT server.

This is the GATT Server setup

```
@ReactMethod
public void startServer(Callback srvCallBack) {
    mBluetoothGattServer = mBluetoothManager.openGattServer(getReactApplicationContext(), mGattServerCallback);
    if (mBluetoothGattServer == null) {
        srvCallBack.invoke(false);
        return;
    }

    BluetoothGattService gattService = new BluetoothGattService(SERVICE_UUID,
            BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCharacteristics = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(SERVICE_UUID, 2, 1);

    String currentDeviceName = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getName();
    boolean isValAdded = mCharacteristics.setValue(currentDeviceName);

    if (isValAdded == false) {
        Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "Can't add value to characteristics.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "Value added to characteristics.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    boolean isCharAdded = gattService.addCharacteristic(mCharacteristics);

    if (isCharAdded == false) {
        Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "Can't add characteristics.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    boolean isServAdded = mBluetoothGattServer.addService(gattService);

    if (isServAdded == true) {
        srvCallBack.invoke(true, gattService.getUuid().toString());
        return;
    }
}
```

Im not sure if the problem is with the GATT server callback, or is it even needed? Here is my callback

```
private BluetoothGattServerCallback mGattServerCallback = new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                return;
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicReadRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, int offset,
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            if (SERVICE_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "Sending device name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mBluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, 0,
                        characteristic.getValue());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "uuid didn't matched.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive regarding "can't read the value". And in your onCharacteristicReadRequest callback, you MUST always call sendResponse (now you don't always do that).

Comment: Thank you that actually solves it

Comment: Im pertaining to the value that characteristic.getValue() is supposed to return.